# Display deferred data in template

Tags: javascript, templates, routes, deferred

## Problem

I'm using [this 20 line router](http://joakimbeng.eu01.aws.af.cm/a-javascript-router-in-20-lines/) to do my routing and templating.

What I am struggling with is using data in the template.

My templating engine is https://github.com/trix/nano.

## What I have

I have a function that gets the users data (at the moment I am just trying to show a message):

```
adrLoadAddressBooks:function() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    var return_response = {};
    data = {
        country_code:config.country_code,
        language_code:config.language_code,
        source:config.source,
        usr_id:app.getCookie('usr_id'),
        login_token:app.getCookie('login_token')
    };
    app.api('adr/list',data,function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        return_response.msg = 'This user has address books.';
        if(!response.result) {
            return_response.msg = 'No address books found.'
        }
        deferred.resolve(return_response);
    },'post');
    return deferred.promise();
},
```

In my router, I get the data like so:

```
jsRouter.route('/adr','adr/index',function() {
    console.log('In route function');
    this.response = events.adrLoadAddressBooks().done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    });
});
```

The `console.log` returns the following:

```
Object {msg: "This user has address books."} // correct
```

And in my template file I have the following:

```
<h4>Address Books</h4>
Message: {response.msg}
<a href="#/adr/create">Create Address Book</a>
```

## Question

It currently only displays the template, no `msg`. If I change `{response.msg}` to just `{response}`, it displays `[Object object]` which is the response object so it is sending something.

How do I access the `msg`?

Comment: The code in question will deliver only "no message" or "No address books found.". Where does the message "This user has address books." come from?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 thanks for the comment. I've updated the question. I was testing other ways of doing it while posting the question, so that's where the message slipped in.

Comment: How is the template is invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing my router quite a bit. I have a `loadPage()` function that looks like this:

```
loadPage:function(page,element,bindData) {
    $.get(page,function(data) {
        element.html(nano(data, bindData));
        app.setPageListeners();
    });
},
```

This was called at the end of my `router()` function (after the template has been found).

```
router:function() {
    app.resetResponse();
    jsRouter.el = jsRouter.el || $('#view');
    var url = $.urlHash() || '/';

    if(typeof route == 'undefined' || typeof route == null) {
        route = jsRouter.routes['404'];
    }
    auth.isLoggedIn();

    if(jsRouter.el && route.controller) {
        jsRouter.loadPage(config.templates + route.template + '.html',jsRouter.el,new route.controller);
    }
},
```

Firstly, what I did was changed my actual `route()` function like so:

```
route:function(path,template,callback) {
    jsRouter.routes[path] = {template: template, callback: callback };
},
```

So now I can pass a callback by setting up my route like this:

```
jsRouter.route('/adr','adr/index',events.adrLoadAddressBooks);
```

I then changed the end of my router to this:

```
 if(jsRouter.el) {
    if(route.callback) {
        jsRouter.loadData(config.templates + route.template + '.html',jsRouter.el,route.callback);
    } else {
        jsRouter.loadPage(config.templates + route.template + '.html',jsRouter.el,"");
    }
}
```

And then created a `loadData` function that waits for a deferred object before continuing, like so:

```
loadData:function(page,element,callback) {
    if(typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback().done(function(data) {
                jsRouter.loadPage(page,element,data);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Could not call " + endpoint);
        }
    } else {
        jsRouter.loadPage(page,element,this);
    }
},
```

My callback, in this case, looks like this:

```
adrLoadAddressBooks:function() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    //do stuff

    app.api('adr/list',data,function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        return_response.msg = 'Below is a list of all your address books.';

        if(!response.result) {
            return_response.msg = 'This user has no address books.';
            deferred.resolve(return_response);
        }

        //build response

        deferred.resolve(return_response);
    },'post');

    return deferred.promise();
},
```

And it works quite well. :) Obviously, if there's stuff that I can improve, add a comment

**EDIT 1**

Added extra step after `route` function.

**EDIT 2**

Full router available on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/E3JZsZTL)

Comment: I can no longer see where `adrLoadAddressBooks()` is called. Before it was called from `jsRouter.route()`.

Comment: Ah OK. It would be good to see the all the code. Some things are not clear. For example, where does `router()` pick up its `route` variable? It's not passed and not local, so it must be in an outer scope, but it's not clear what that outer scope is or how the variable is set.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 added the file to pastebin. Have a look. Just remember, it's still in development. Like today alone I've changed a lot already. This is the file as it was at the end of Friday. Obviously, if you can suggest improvements, you are more than welcome to.

Comment: The main thing I would change is the overall wrapper. `jsRouter` would probably work better as a [module](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) of your app or a jQuery plugin. Either approach would allow you to keep some functions and vars private and expose only public methods. A plain object doesn't really offer this possibility. Also, after playing around with the code for a bit, I found that the `.loadData()` method wasn't necessary - it kind of vanished after a rewrite of `.router()`.